# AVoid Postback on OnClick Event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onclick, postback

I have a `Javascript` function

```
show()
{
alert("hello");
}
```

which runs on ASP Button OnClick Event.

When I click the button of alert message box showing "hello", postback occurs. Is there any way I cant prevent this postback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
return false;
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do `show(); return false;` in the button's onclick handler.

Answer (score 3):

```
onclick="show();return false;"
```

Answer (score 1):

it's very simple:
insert aber the "Alert('msg');" a "return false;".

so:

```
function show()
{
alert('Hallo');
return false;
 }
```

Comment: This won't work! The return must be inside the onclick handler.